# Boolean cut not working

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

As you can see from the image I would like to cut the excess part of the green mesh which is in the green mesh of the head.

Both head and hair mesh is 2 separate objects with all scale rotation and position applied.

I have tried with the boolean operation but one of the 2 objects is always disappearing as a final result.

Any Idea what is causing it and how can I manage to do it?  Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have the boolean modifier set to `Difference`.

If you set the boolean modifier to **`Union`**, The objects won't disappear.

If the union doesn't work, a workaround could always be to duplicate one of the objects and then do boolean difference, so even if one object disappears, it won't be a problem since it's already duplicated without a boolean ;).

Comment: the problem is that I do not want the 2 objects to be one I want them to still be separate in the end result.  All I want is to remove the excess mesh that is inside the head.

Comment: @ronin074 it's the boolean `modifier`, of course, it will be separate in the end! Even if you apply (not add, "apply") the boolean modifier (which is not a necessity) it will still be separate. I recommend you watch some tutorials on the boolean mdofier.